# Saving struct data to a void* variable

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux

I am working on implementing BFSK algorithm on a DSP processor and need to simulate the implementation on LINUX using predefined DSP infra files. The input data in coming in the the form of a float array. The individual bits are extracted from the input one by one. The modulated output is generated in the fprm of a typdef struct, which is a consists of two float variables (real and imaginary parts since the modulated data is a complex baseband signal). But the DSP simulation needs the output to be saved into a void pointer array. This cant be changed as the DSP APIs need it in the form of a void pointer. The definition of the struct is as follows :

```
typedef struct {
float re;
float im;
}complex_float;
```

I am able to copy the data into the void pointer using memcpy :

```
sigbuf=(float *)malloc(bitsPerBlk*sigLen*sizeof(complex_float));

memcpy(sigbuf, comSig, (bitsPerBlk*sigLen*sizeof(complex_float)));
```

sigbuf is the void pointer array where the ouput would be saved and comSig is the complex_float array where the modulated output is saved. The thing is I am not able to access the invidual values of the sigbuf array. I tried this as well

```
sigbuf=(complex_float *)malloc(bitsPerBlk*sigLen*sizeof(complex_float));
```

But still it doesnot work.

If someone can help me out it would be very helpful for me.

Thanks,
Anshu

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "doesn't work".  What, specifically, doesn't work?

Comment: `sigbuf is the void pointer array where the ouput would be saved and comSig is the complex_float array` Please put your declarations and definitions in source code, not in text. Text is for comments and explanation.

Comment: Show us the code that how you access the invidual values of the sigbuf array

Comment: Where does `comSig` comes from, what format it has? How do you define sigbuf? `But still it doesnot work` -- AHA your screen is black, it calculates to 42 or it can't drive a car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here. Why don't you just make a copy of comSig to sigBuf then pass it to your API?

```
complex_float *sigBuf = malloc(TOTAL_SIZE_OF_COMSIG);
memcpy(sigBuf, comSig, TOTAL_SIZE_OF_COMSIG);
```

I don't know the docs on your function but it sounds like your API takes a void pointer to some buffer of data and perhaps its length or number of elements.

```
dsp_api(sigBuf, sigBufSize);
```

I think you are misunderstanding what a void pointer is and what your function wants. A void pointer is just a generic pointer to some data. It's the functions way of taking in any data, then probably casting it to your complex_float structure to operate on the data.

As a future reference to why you weren't able to dereference a void pointer is because it has no size. You'd have to cast it to a type then you'd be able to dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

if sigbuf is of type (void *) then your line

```
sigbuf=(complex_float *)malloc(bitsPerBlk*sigLen*sizeof(complex_float));
```

should be able to be changed to

```
sigbuf=(void *)malloc(bitsPerBlk*sigLen*sizeof(complex_float));
```

as left of the malloc is simply a cast!

Comment: This will make no difference in C.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - If it's a compile error then it might (dependent on compiler).  He hasn't really defined his error (or what isn't working).

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that, my bad that i was not able to explain my point clearly. The declarations are as follows

```
void *sigbuf;
complex_float *comSig;
```

> complex_float

is a struct consisting of two float elements.

> sigbuf

will store the modulated data which is then passed further for transmission system.

> comSig

is a complex_float array (basically an array of sin and cosine function ouputs).

The DSP infrastructure needs the modulated output in

> sigbuf

which has been calculated and saved in

> comSig

.
Both somSig and sigbuf are predefined in the DSP infrastructure.

My problem was that I was able to copy the entire comSig aaray to sigbuf array, but was not able to access the individual elements 
of the sigbuf array.

Any ways I was able to circumvent the problem by passing the address of the comSig array itself via a global pointer variable.The DSP infrastructure
gives the freedom to do so. So, for now the problem seems to have been fixed.
Thanks again, Anshu.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the destination address, sigbuf, is properly aligned.  For example, the DSP may require that 4-byte float values must be aligned on 4-byte boundaries.  memcpy() likely does not check alignment and will copy the individual bytes without complaint.  But if sigbuf does not have the proper alignment then you will not be able to access the contents as a float (i.e., the data will be corrupted when it is read from memory into a register).